# jquery event propagation issue in IE9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Well this is a weird problem, and I have no idea how to go about debugging this one, so any tips and suggestions are appreciated.

I have a calendar(yui-calendar) which is absolutely positioned with everything inside it, relatively positioned. What I wanted to do is, if I click outside the calendar, it should close otherwise not...

```
$('html').click(function(e){
        console.log("Event reached html level "+$(e.target).attr("class"));
        if($(".yui-calcontainer.withtitle").is(":visible"))
        {
            $(".yui-calcontainer.withtitle").hide();
        }
    })

    $(".yui-calcontainer.withtitle,#calendar_img_1").click(function(e){
        console.log("Event reached icon level "+$(e.target).attr("class"));
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

This works fine in FF and even IE8, but in IE9, any click inside the calendar seems to bubble up to the html level. Weird thing is that it completely overlooks the `.yui-calcontainer.withtitle` even though it is in the page, but works ok with `#calendar_img_1`which is basically the icon I click on to open up the calendar.

[You can see the issue here](http://wholesaleflowersinc.com/flowers/white-alstroemeria-flower-3.html) (click on the icon in the "Choose Delivery Date" section on the right hand side of the page)

Comment: JavaScript errors could prevent the event from being stopped.

Comment: @Jack yeh, you might be right, but then again, I don't see any particular error between the click and the bubbling phase, also it works in ie8 and FF, so it is something ie9 specific.

Answer (score 0):

try `cancelBubble`..

try this

```
 $(".yui-calcontainer.withtitle,#calendar_img_1").click(function(e){
  if(e.stopPropagation){  // check stoppropogation is avilable
     e.stopPropagation();  //use stopPropogation
  }else{
     e.cancelBubble = true;  // for ie
  }
});
```

link about [cancelBubble](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but sadly it didn't work, I updated my code as per your suggestion in the link above

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't tell exactly why it wouldn't work in IE9, this is my typical approach for popup windows that are closed when you click outside of it. It's kind of a delicate dance between event handlers ;-)

```
function openCalendar()
{
  // show the calendar
  $('#calendar').show();

  // setup one-time event handlers to close it
  $(document)
    .one('click', closeCalendar)
    .one('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.which==27) {
        closeCalendar();
      }
    });

  // make sure we stop propagation, otherwise the calendar is closed immediately
  return false;
}

function closeCalendar()
{
    if ($("#calendar").is(":visible")) {
        $("#calendar").hide();
    }
    // we don't need these anymore
    $(document).unbind('click keydown');
}

// make sure events don't bubble up from clicking on the calendar itself
$("#calendar").on('click', function(e) {
  return false;
});

// register the click handler to open it
$('.open-calendar').on('click', openCalendar);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/igocap/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Though this isn't exactly a solution to the issue, but I did manage to solve it for the time being with a roundabout solution. But since this is a very costly solution in terms of performance, I am still open to other ideas and suggestions as to why propagation won't stop in IE9 in my case.

Anyway, what I did is, in the html click handler, check if the current event target is a child of yui-calendar, if yes, I skip closing it.

```
$('html').click(function(e){
        if($(".yui-calcontainer.withtitle").is(":visible") && $(e.target).parents(".yui-calcontainer.withtitle").length<=0)
        {
            $(".yui-calcontainer.withtitle").hide();
        }
    })
```